# Refactoring the logic of a return value

Tags: c#, null

In my method I have something like this:

```
returnValue = null; 
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pa.Phone))
{
    if (pa.Length != 10 && member == Schema.Phone.Name)
    {
        returnValue = new stuff;
    }
}

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pa.OtherPhone))
{
    if (pa.OtherPhone.Length != 10 && member == Schema.OtherPhone.Name)
    {
        returnValue = new stuff;
    }
}

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pa.Fax))
{
    if (pa.Fax.Length != 10 && member == Schema.Fax.Name)
    {
        returnValue = new stuff
    }
}

// even more similar ifs...

// at the end of method: return returnValue;
```

How can I refactor this logic? Note that new stuff is always the same for all the `if`s.

Comment: Is the first nested if supposed to be `Pa.Phone.Length` rather than `Pa.Length`?

Comment: It would be nice if you included the entire method (even if it's long), so we have actual context and don't have to guess about what `pa` and `member` might be. Also `new stuff` should probably be `new Stuff();` ...and then we can help you come up with a more descriptive title ;)

Comment: @Mat'sMug Ulugbek Umirov got it right with the info I had posted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `member` is `string`.

```
Func<string, string, bool> f = (p, m) => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(p) && p.Length != 10 && member == m;
if (f(pa.Phone, Schema.Phone.Name) ||
    f(pa.OtherPhone, Schema.OtherPhone.Name) ||
    f(pa.Fax, Schema.Fax.Name))
{
    return new stuff;
}
else
{
    return null;
}
```

Comment: yes, member is a string.

Answer (score 1):

A little improve to the previous post ?

```
Func<string, string, bool> f = (p, m) => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(p) && p.Length != 10 && member == m;
Func<dynamic[], bool> inFunc = o => o.Any(k => k);

return inFunc(new []{f(pa.Phone, Schema.Phone.Name), f(pa.OtherPhone, Schema.OtherPhone.Name),f(pa.Fax, Schema.Fax.Name)}) 
            ? (object) new stuff()
            : null;
```